# How to make validation rules for storing and update users if there are unique attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I use `username` as an `id` to login and made username and email as unique. 
Whenever I made username and email, validation rules check coming data and there is no problem with it because `username` and `email` would be new and unique. 
The problem occurs when I update. when I update the attributes, I don't need to change the username mostly but the rules are expecting `unique, username`.
**what is the best practice for updating unique attributes with validation rules?**.

Update user method

```
 public function updateUser($req, $id)
    {
        $user = User::where('user_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $user->username = $req->input('username');
        $user->password = Hash::make($req->input('password'));
        $user->email = $req->input('email');
        $user->first_name = $req->input('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $req->input('last_name');
        $user->phone = $req->input('phone');
        $user->emergency_phone = $req->input('emergency_phone');
        $user->profile_photo = $req->input('profile_photo');
        $user->role = $req->input('role');
        $user->status = $req->input('status');

        $user->save();
        return $this->filterUsers([$user]);
    }
```

Rules

```
  protected $rules = [

        'username' => 'required|max:20|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
        // **in Production **
        // 'password' => [
        //     'required',
        //     'min:6',
        //     'regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
        //     'confirmed'
        // ],
        /**
         * Three of the five rules. 
         * English uppercase characters (A – Z)
         * English lowercase characters (a – z)
         * Base 10 digits (0 – 9)
         * Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
         * Unicode characters
         */

        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:5',
        'role' => 'required'


    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'username' => 'required|max:20|unique:users,username,' . $id',
```

if your users table primary key is `id`, if it is something else like `user_id`, then it will become

```
'username'  =>  'required|email|unique:user,username,' . $request->input('user_id') . ',userid',
```

so syntax is

```
'input_field' => 'unique:<table name>,<column name for this input field>, <unique id>, <unique id column in table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

At edit time it will check for a unique username so we avoid unique for a current edit id

In the update method your validation rules as per below:

```
protected $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|max:20|unique:users,username,' . $id',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $id',
        'password' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:5',
        'role' => 'required'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use laravel validator class in controller `Use Validator;`

And use something like this:

```
$error = Validator::make($req->all(), $rules);
```

More examples [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) in docs of Validation.