# Laravel validation rule, combination of two field needs to be unique

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I need the combination of menuId and foodItem name to be unique, but food item id is input value

I tried

```
 return [
            'foodItemId' => 'required|unique:food_items,id,' . 1 . ',menuId',
        ];
```

and interestingly, I have answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56204862/5321614), but could not make it work here!

Also, I tried

```
 'foodItemId' => [
             'required', 
             Rule::unique('food_items', 'id')->where(function($query) use($menu){
                 return $query->where('id', request()->input('foodItemId'))->where(function($qr) use($menu){
                     return $qr->where('menu_id', '!=', $menu);
                 });
             })
         ],
```

and

```
'foodItemId' => ['required', Rule::unique('food_items', 'id')->where(function ($query) use ($menu) {
                return $query->where('menu_id', '!=', $menu);
            })],
```

and

```
'foodItemId' => [
                'required', 'numeric', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($menu) {
                    $exists =  FoodItem::where('id', request()->input('foodItemId'))
                        ->where('menu_id', $menu)
                        ->exists();

                    if (!$exists) {
                        return $fail('Your error message goes here.');
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround for now, I hope I will get a better solution

```
public function rules()
    {
        $menu = $this->menu->id;
        return [
            'foodItemId' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($menu) {
                $foodItemName = FoodItem::find($value)->name;
                $validationStatus = FoodItem::where('name', $foodItemName)->where('menu_id', $menu)->get()->isNotEmpty();

                if ($validationStatus) {
                    $fail('This item is already in the menu.');
                }
            },
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change not equal `!=` to equal `=`:

```
'foodItemId' => [
    'required', 
    Rule::unique('food_items', 'id')->where(function ($query) use ($menu) {
        return $query->where('menu_id', $menu);
    })],
```

Comment: Already tried, it is showing already exists for new food_item too.